Why does not Wilczek paper on fractional statistics in 2+1D extend to 3+1D?
I am currently going through Wilzcek's paper called "Quantum Mechanics of Fractional-Spin Particles" for 2+1D. I am especially interested in his derivation of the single anyon case, and I am trying to think as to why his derivation does not extend to 3+1D.
In his paper, he starts by looking at a single example (One anyon). In this case, he views the anyon as a charge-flux composite. He presents an azimuthal vector potential for the flux tube, and finds a gauge to eliminate this vector potential. Consequently, he has to compensate for this gauge in his wavefunction, which adds a phase. Then he assumes some $2\pi$ periodicity, and concludes fractional statistics based on some allowed angular wave functions $e^{im\phi}$.
My first question is, where are these angular wave functions retrieved from? And secondly, why does this derivation fail in 3+1D? From the single-anyon case, I can’t identify any obvious step that would inherently prevent a 3+1D extension. To me it seems like choosing an infinitely thin long solenoid in 3+1D would yield a similar result, but maybe that can not be considered a charge-flux composite?
IDEA
Okay so I have tried thinking about this a bit further, and I think I might have come up with an idea as to why this does not extend naturally to 3+1D.  My idea is that, to retrieve the 3+1D case, the Aharonov-Bohm (AB) phase observed in 2+1D needs to vanish first of all.
In 2+1D we have a single symmetry under exchange: permutation symmetry. Whether we exchange the particles clockwise or anticlockwise matters here.
In 3+1D we have permutation symmetry alongside orientation symmetry. This means that the clockwise exchange is topologically equivalent to the anti-clockwise exchange, and so the AB effect would contribute with a phase to the wavefunction, but with different signs in both cases. But since they are topologically equivalent, then this AB contribution would neccessarily have to be zero.
What do you think?

Check out Leinaas and Myrheim, they present the 2D context quite clearly if I remember correctly. It boils down to braiding statistics and what allowed interchanges of particles are allowed in 2D vs 3D, given the spin-statistics theorem.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer Will do! Thanks.
